# Rust solution for RAII pattern to modify another object on new() and drop()

Tags: c++, rust, raii

It's pretty standard in C++ to have an arrangement like:

```cpp
// Some object that you want to manipulate
class DataType 
{ 
public: 
    foo() {} 
    bar() {} 
};

// Some class that manipulates a DataType on construct and destruct
// Your typical RAII scope side effect type thing
class DoFooAndBar
{
public:
    DoFooAndBar(DataType& dataType) : m_dataType(dataType)
    { m_dataType.foo(); }

    ~DoFooAndBar() 
    { m_dataType.bar(); }

private:
    DataType& m_dataType
}
```

I tried to do something like this in Rust, but I ran into issues where the DoFooAndBar took a mutable reference, and then subsequent code could not take an immutable reference.  I can deal with this problem with your typical `Rc::RefCell` hack, but I wonder if there's a right way of doing things like this without resorting to that.

Here's my Rust code, cooked down as much as I could for this question:

```
/// Symbol table example to for a hypothetical script interpreter
/// Simplified to demonstrate issues with borrowing references
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// For our purposes a frame from is just a string->string map
type SymbolFrame = HashMap<String, String>;

/// Our stack of frames is just a vector of stack frame
/// Not performant, but that's not the point
type SymbolFrameStack = Vec<SymbolFrame>;

/// The SymbolTable type contains a stack of symbol frames
/// and routines for working with them
pub struct SymbolTable
{
    frames: SymbolFrameStack
}
impl SymbolTable
{
    /// Start with an initial stack with one frame
    pub fn new() -> Self { SymbolTable { frames: vec![SymbolFrame::new()] } }

    /// Push and pop frames
    pub fn push(&mut self) { self.frames.push(SymbolFrame::new()); }
    pub fn pop(&mut self) { self.frames.pop(); }

    /// See if a symbol exists by name anywhere in the frames
    pub fn contains(&self, name: &str) -> bool {
        for frame in self.frames.iter() { 
            if frame.contains_key(name) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/// Push a frame on new(); pop the frame on drop()
pub struct SymbolStacker<'a> { table: &'a mut SymbolTable }
impl<'a> SymbolStacker<'a>
{
    pub fn new(table: &'a mut SymbolTable) -> SymbolStacker {
        table.push();
        SymbolStacker { table }
    }
}
impl<'a> Drop for SymbolStacker<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.table.pop();
    }
}

#[test]
fn bad_test_symbol_table() {
    // Create our table for testing
    let table = &mut SymbolTable::new();
    {
        // Enter a new scope of code, pushing a new stack frame
        let _stacker1 = SymbolStacker::new(table);
        {
            // ...a lot of other recursive code
            // ...presumably passing the table struct around in some way
            // ...we just try to see if a symbol exists in the table
            assert!(!table.contains("foo"));
        }

        assert!(table.contains("foo"));
    }
}
```

It generates a compilation error when running the tests:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*table` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

I understand the error, I'm just looking for advice on how best to do this sort of thing in Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you’re looking for, but I think the best answer to this question is “Writing code this way in Rust is messy because rust isn’t designed to be used this way.” Using RAII scoped side effects in Rust is a tell that you’re a C++ developer trying to write C++ code in Rust in the same way that spamming `new` in C++ is a tell you’re a Java developer writing Java code in C++. To be sure when answering this question, I quickly looked trough some reputable libraries, and could not find a single instance of it where not absolutely necessary.

However, if you really need this kind of thing for some data structure, which can be the case for lower-level data structures, probably the most idiomatic way is with `unsafe{}`, simply using a raw pointer. This is the way file handles are dealt with in the standard library, for example. However, if you’re still learning rust, and especially if you’re doing this as an exercise, it might be wiser to try to refactor your code to not have RAII side effects, as those are generally frowned upon, especially for high-level code.

There is a reason there is no real safe way to do this. Rust safety is not just safety when running, even a std::process::exit should be safe according to the type system, which would result in a memory leak even in the indeed idiomatic C++ code.

Comment: Fair enough.  So if you want to do the RAII type of thing for cases like a symbol table stack that needs to get pushed and popped in the course of an interpreter working with the call stack, what's the recommended approach?  Are you saying that Rust isn't suitable for writing things like script interpreters?

Comment: @MichaelBalloni I'm not sure about the details of the usecase you are talking about, but he isn't saying Rust isn't suitable. He is saying it isn't suitable if you try to implement it using C++ idioms. It requires a rethinking of the problem, and then ways will be found to implement those things without those idioms. It's just hard to find new ways for programmers that are too specialized on another language already; sometimes it's easier to learn Rust if you have no pre-occupation.

Comment: I'm sorry @Finomnis, are you saying that C++ programmers shouldn't learn how to use Rust?  I'm asking this question because I'm trying to learn Rust, and I know what I'm trying to do, and in some way I need the same stack frame push/pop scoped to a call frame stuff in Rust that I do in C++.  I can do Rc::RefCell hacks, I just want to know how to "do this right" in Rust.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelBalloni No, not at all, I'm sorry if it came across this way :) I just wanted to confront you with the fact that a rethinking might be required. Why do you think `Rc<RefCell>` is a hack? It sounds like it could be a suited usecase for it. `&mut` isn't - you probably want to push more than a single value on the stack. So interior mutability might be the right way.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the problem. Rust, being a language inspired on the ML language family, is more than suitable for a script interpreter, you just need to use a different architecture. Intuitively, for a script interpreter, I'd use recursion: Make a Rust function that can get the result of a scripted function, and then call than function in itself for nested function calls. You can also emulate the stack, if you want, it's a bit more boiler-plate-y. Just create two Vectors, one for call, one for return. I'll edit in a quick example in the main answer.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  I've got a SymbolTable class that lives alongside the call stack.  As things like function calls and loop bodies and such come and go, I have to push and pop the symbol table.  Is there an elegant way to ensure that the table gets popped when the recursive script function returns from a loop body or user function?  This is the root of my question.

Comment: @Egeau, thanks for being patient and taking the time.  That's an interesting example, but I don't see how it relates to managing a data structure alongside the call stack.  Doing everything on the call stack is possible, but lacking RAII or try / finally, how does one ensure that things are undone when the call stack is popped (when the interpreter function exits)?

Comment: *"but lacking RAII or try / finally, how does one ensure that things are undone when the call stack is popped"* - `Drop` is the correct approach. The problem here is not based around `Drop`, it's based around ownership. Rust is very strict with ownership, and if you want to modify something, then your reference to that object must be the only `&mut` reference to it, and the compiler must be able to verify that. I think this is the core of your problem. I feel like you are trying to have many places mutate the call stack simultaneously, which would be against that compiler rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Rc<RefCell>` would be a viable solution. Although I would question the entire architecture of pop-on-drop. For example, what should happen here?

```rust
// Create our table for testing
let table = &mut SymbolTable::new();
{
    // Enter a new scope of code, pushing a new stack frame
    let _stacker1 = SymbolStacker::new(table);
    {
        // Enter another scope
        let _stacker2 = SymbolStacker::new(table);

        // Drop the first stacker. This is valid use of your API.
        drop(_stacker1);

        // stacker2 still exists. What should the state of the table be
        // now? In your implementation, dropping `stacker1` would have
        // dropped the frame of `stacker2`. Is that desired behavior?
        // If not, the Rust-y way would be to prevent this usage on API level.
    }
}
```

This is valid use of your API. In Rust, one paradigm is that APIs should be only usable in the correct way.

There is ways to achieve this, of course. I don't know your entire usecase, but something like this makes sense to me and compiles fine:

```rust
/// Symbol table example to for a hypothetical script interpreter
/// Simplified to demonstrate issues with borrowing references
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// For our purposes a frame from is just a string->string map
type SymbolFrame = HashMap<String, String>;

/// Our stack of frames is just a vector of stack frame
/// Not performant, but that's not the point
type SymbolFrameStack = Vec<SymbolFrame>;

/// The SymbolTable type contains a stack of symbol frames
/// and routines for working with them
pub struct SymbolTable {
    frames: SymbolFrameStack,
}
impl SymbolTable {
    /// Start with an initial stack with one frame
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SymbolTable {
            frames: vec![SymbolFrame::new()],
        }
    }

    /// Push and pop frames
    pub fn push(&mut self) {
        self.frames.push(SymbolFrame::new());
    }
    pub fn pop(&mut self) {
        self.frames.pop();
    }

    /// See if a symbol exists by name anywhere in the frames
    pub fn contains(&self, name: &str) -> bool {
        for frame in self.frames.iter() {
            if frame.contains_key(name) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, name: String, value: String) {
        self.frames.last_mut().unwrap().insert(name, value);
    }
}

/// Push a frame on new(); pop the frame on drop()
pub struct SymbolStacker<'a> {
    table: &'a mut SymbolTable,
}
impl SymbolStacker<'_> {
    pub fn new(table: &mut SymbolTable) -> SymbolStacker {
        table.push();
        SymbolStacker { table }
    }

    pub fn get_table(&mut self) -> &mut SymbolTable {
        self.table
    }

    pub fn new_frame(&mut self) -> SymbolStacker {
        SymbolStacker::new(self.table)
    }
}
impl<'a> Drop for SymbolStacker<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.table.pop();
    }
}

#[test]
fn bad_test_symbol_table() {
    // Create our table for testing
    let table = &mut SymbolTable::new();
    {
        let mut stacker = SymbolStacker::new(table);
        stacker
            .get_table()
            .insert("foo".to_string(), "abc".to_string());

        assert!(stacker.get_table().contains("foo"));
        assert!(!stacker.get_table().contains("bar"));

        // Enter a new scope of code, pushing a new stack frame
        {
            let mut stacker = stacker.new_frame();

            stacker
                .get_table()
                .insert("bar".to_string(), "42".to_string());

            assert!(stacker.get_table().contains("foo"));
            assert!(stacker.get_table().contains("bar"));
        }

        assert!(stacker.get_table().contains("foo"));
        assert!(!stacker.get_table().contains("bar"));
    }
}
```

Note that the following code is now a compilation error:

```rust
#[test]
fn bad_test_symbol_table() {
    // Create our table for testing
    let table = &mut SymbolTable::new();
    {
        let mut stacker = SymbolStacker::new(table);
        stacker
            .get_table()
            .insert("foo".to_string(), "abc".to_string());

        assert!(stacker.get_table().contains("foo"));
        assert!(!stacker.get_table().contains("bar"));

        // Enter a new scope of code, pushing a new stack frame
        {
            let mut stacker2 = stacker.new_frame();

            stacker2
                .get_table()
                .insert("bar".to_string(), "42".to_string());

            // Drop outer stacker
            drop(stacker);

            assert!(stacker2.get_table().contains("foo"));
            assert!(stacker2.get_table().contains("bar"));
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `stacker` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:94:18
   |
87 |             let mut stacker2 = stacker.new_frame();
   |                                ------------------- borrow of `stacker` occurs here
...
94 |             drop(stacker);
   |                  ^^^^^^^ move out of `stacker` occurs here
95 |
96 |             assert!(stacker2.get_table().contains("foo"));
   |                     -------------------- borrow later used here
```

Of course your usecase might be more complex, and carrying around a `&mut` reference might not be the right choice. But I think this would require more context in your question. Rust is a very strict language, and many problems require very specific solutions.

Comment: Yeah, passing around something sometimes mutable and sometime immutable by reference through the life of a sprawling script interpreter, I get the sense that that will never work.  Rc::RefCell it is.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelBalloni There might be ways to achieve that, but I agree that especially for a Rust newcommer it will get very complicated and frustrating quick. I don't think there is an inherent issue with `Rc<RefCell>` in this case. You still get some assurances: It's not `Send` or `Sync`, meaning, it is checked at compile time that only one single thread accesses it. And the borrow checks are also all still in place, just moved to runtime. As long as you make sure that you don't recursively borrow it twice (which would cause a runtime error), it should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the `table` stored in the field via a method, and then code could access it:

```rust
impl<'a> SymbolStacker<'a> {
    pub fn get(&mut self) -> &mut SymbolTable { self.table }
}

#[test]
fn bad_test_symbol_table() {
    // Create our table for testing
    let table = &mut SymbolTable::new();
    {
        // Enter a new scope of code, pushing a new stack frame
        let _stacker1 = SymbolStacker::new(table);
        let table = _stacker1.get()
        {
            // ...a lot of other recursive code
            // ...presumably passing the table struct around in some way
            // ...we just try to see if a symbol exists in the table
            assert!(!table.contains("foo"));
        }

        assert!(table.contains("foo"));
    }
}
```

You can even implement `Deref` and `DerefMut` to allow easier access to the table (though I will not necessarily recommend it), or have a macro that creates a `SymbolStacker` and rebinds `table`.

Comment: The problem is table.contains("foo") will fail because contains() wants an immutable &self reference, but table is a mutable reference from _stacker1.get(), so it cannot be borrowed.  Also the table.contains() call could be in some deep forest of nested recursion where _stacker1 would be unavailable.

Comment: @MichaelBalloni A mutable reference can be used when a shared one is expected. About the second concern, if you can pass `table` to be used you can also pass `_stacker1` in the same way.